# nginx + PHP-FPM disable PHP functions only for certain virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, php, virtualhost, php-fpm

How can I disable some php functions only for some of(currently only 1) virtualhosts on my Nginx+PHP-FPM stack?

Comment: Which PHP functions? What is your current nginx configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You can make a separate pool for your host and put restricted functions in there like this (on the last line):

```
[example.com]
listen = 127.0.0.1:9001
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
user = web1
group = client0
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 20
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
chdir = /
php_admin_value[open_basedir] = /var/www/www.example.com:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin
php_admin_value[disable_functions] = dl,exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,parse_ini_file,show_source
```

Answer (score 0):

Its spelt out in the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) on setting up process pools - use environment vars to append to the disable_functions ini setting.

Answer (score -1):

In fact, seems it can't.

`disable_functions` can only be set in php.ini (*PHP_INI_SYSTEM*).

Although the PHP pool from FPM seems like a [separate procces](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50802#1263932575) - see https://supportex.net/blog/2012/02/lemp-disabling-php-functions/

Comment: It's possible to add (they are appended to the list from php.ini) custom disabled functions in FPM pool configuration like described at https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php